# Passing event Invocation to other class

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, events, architecture

Yes, I know, that you can't Invoke events from another class.
I am trying to implement StatusEffects System.
In my particular case, I just can't think of better workaround, than passing event Invocation to another class.
So I would like to here some opinions/advices.

Imagine there are 2 types of possible effects:

1) Stats script modifying

2) Health script modifying

And this scripts already have this logic in them.
So all my effects have to do - send them an event(ChangeStats event, etc).

I don't want to let each effect have it's own events, and subscribe this scripts' methods(Health.OnHealthChanged,Stats.OnStatsChanged) every time new effect is being added.

So I have this StatusController class, with this events, and my Health/Stats scripts' methods are already subscribed to them.
So determining the actual effect of StatusEffect = firing this events from StatusController.

So I created public methods to invoke this events.

```
public abstract class StatusEffect
{
    string[] statsToChange;
    float[] valuesToAdd;
    float healthValue;

    protected virtual void Apply(StatusController controller)
    {
        controller.OnStatsChanged(statsToChange, valuesToAdd);
    }

    protected virtual void Tick(StatusController controller)
    {
        controller.OnHealthChanged(healthValue);
    }
}
```

Here is my StatusController class:

```
public class StatusController: MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void StatsEventHandler(string[] names, float[] values);
    public delegate void HealthEventHandler(value);
    public event StatsEventHandler OnStatsChangedEvent;
    public event HealthEventHandler OnHealthChangedEvent;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        OnStatsChangedEvent += GetComponent<Stats>().OnStatsChanged;
        OnHealthChangedEvent += GetComponent<Health>().OnHealthChanged;
    }

    public void OnStatsChanged(string[] names, float[] values)
    {
        OnStatsChangedEvent(names,values);
    }

    public void OnHealthChanged(float value)
    {
        OnHealthChangedEvent(value);
    }

    public void OnStatusEffectAdded(StatusEffect effect)
    {
        effect.Apply(this); //this actually calls OnStatsChangedEvent(effect.statsToChange, effect.valuesToAdd)
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (tickTime...)
            effect.Tick(this);
    }
}
```

The main point is that actual effect's logic already implemented in some other component, and it should just be called, but without passing reference to it's component (like using GetComponent and passing it as parameter, I don't really want that).

And I also don't want to make public fields in StatusEffect class for values etc.
Because there may come up some new kind of effect, and it can require more fields, then I will have to change my StatusController script and so on and so on.
This way I'll have to add events only to StatusController, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a status effect script and attach/remove it to your gameobject as necessary

Since Unity3D uses a pseudo composite-entity system, you can glom a status script onto the gameobject to affect it in whatever way you want. If I were going to poison my player, I would attach a `PoisonStatus` script to the gameobject and in its Update() method, affect the gameobject as needed (call some `GetComponent<Damageable>().Damage(float or int)` method from `PoisonStatus`).

```
// Assume Status is a class that inherits MonoBehaviour and sets up a timer and bool
//  to show that your status is able to damage the attached gameobject
public class PoisonStatus : Status
{
    // Do your setup for damage value
    [...]

    // Affect your player
    void Update()
    {
        // canDamageGameObject is a bool based on timer and current time in Status
        if (canDamageGameObject)
            affectedGameObjectDamageComponent.Damage(damageValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is definitely not what I am trying/going/willing to do. And this is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Minimizing runtime AddComponent calls, avoiding Monobehaviours whenever possible.

Comment: Using simple c# classes allows creating like 10k instances per frame without noticable delay. Try adding 10k components / instantiating 10k monos per frame :)

Comment: Are you looking to have status effects on ~10k objects? To me, it sounds like you're taking a solution and applying it to your problem instead of the other way around. If you're looking for a C# specific solution, I would remove the Unity3d tag and hopefully someone with more in-depth C# knowledge can answer it.

Comment: StatusEffects are like 1/100 of things, that have to be instantiated in runtime. Using your approach, it will be logical, to build all game around it. So yes, there will be like thousands of runtime calls for AddComponent/GetComponent/Monobehaviour.Instantiate using this approach. And my first priority - understanding good architecture approaches, not building a game.